# Alternative energy solutions

Tags: energy

I would like to ask if it is possible to set up an inverter using  a string of batteries 6v each connected for 48 volts. The inverter output is 8kw at 120vac 1phase noramaly.so I want to plug in a battery charger at 120volts ac from the same inverter and connect it to the batteries to recharge them in DC. Is that possible and what may be the outcome, please and thanks.

Comment: You aren't try to create perpetual motion, are you? Physics has a dim view of such activities.

Comment: Why not skip the inverter and battery charger and just plug the batteries into themselves?

Comment: @immibis: aren't all batteries connected to themselves anyway?

Comment: When manufacturers want to do a high power/long run test on a seriouly big inverter or battery charger, they often connect the two like this so that their lab power supply (that they are paying for) only has to supply the losses, not the throughput. Funnily enough, no-one has ever observed power coming out of this sort of arrangement, or even being lossless, power always absorbed in losses.

Comment: @immibis That reminded me of those portable phone chargers that I plug on their own USB charging port and they begin "charging" lol

Comment: Closing since hairbrain schemes for perpetual motion machines are a waste of time.  And -1 for the stupidity.

Comment: @dandavis that's the joke

Answer (score 7):

The outcome will be an expensive and somewhat inefficient battery discharger.

The inverter will draw more energy from the battery than it produces, and the charger will also draw more power from the inverter than it produces - you lose power at each step in the chain.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to ask if it is possible to set up an inverter using a string of batteries 6v each connected for 48 volts. The inverter output is 8kw at 120vac 1phase noramaly.so I want to plug in a battery charger at 120volts ac from the same inverter and connect it to the batteries to recharge them in DC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foJmib.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The recharge yourself scheme.*

How it works:

- If your 8 kW inverter is 80% effecient (pretty good) then to get 8 kW out you will need to put 10 kW in. The 2 kW losses will be given off as heat.
- Let's say you can find a charger that is 87.5% effecient. You feed in 8 kW and get 7 kW of charge current out. The 1 kW losses will be given off as heat.

The net result is batteries will discharge at 3 kWh every hour or a continuous drain of 3 kW.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLHVIj.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Scheme proposed by @immibus.*

This scheme eliminates all the losses of Figure 1.

> Is that possible and what may be the outcome, please and thanks.

See above. Ask for clarification if required.

Answer (score 0):

The total amount of Energy in a physical system is always conserved. This has been independently verified by experiment for hundreds of years, and every time we think we find something that violates the principle of Conservation of Energy, it always turns out to be just some part of the system that wasn't correctly accounted for. This principle is the bedrock of how we are able to design things. All AC and DC circuits analysis is built on this principle.

Often in electronics we deal in electrical Power, which is the rate at which Energy is delivered. (Don't get the technical terms Energy and Power as used in Physics mixed up with the English words. In physics these words have very specific technical meaning for measurable quantities.)

For a DC-to-AC Inverter, the input Power is DC Voltage multiplied by DC Current. The output Power is RMS (DC equivalent) Voltage multiplied by RMS Current. Some of the input Power is leaked out as thermal Energy (heat).

If the inverter is delivering 120Vrms AC to a load that demands 1A (and assuming a power factor of 100%), then the inverter is delivering 120W of Power to the load. The inverter is also leaking out some additional power in the form of heat. Suppose the inverter is operating at 33% efficiency: that would mean it is delivering 120W of electrical Power to the load and delivering 240W of thermal heat to warm up the room, so the inverter is drawing 120W + 240W = 360W of power from the input source. If the input is 48V DC, then the input current must be 360W / 48V = 7.5A of current.

Obviously we would like the power converter to be as close to 100% efficient as possible. Unfortunately it's not like there is a knob you can adjust to turn up the efficiency. Instead it's a whole series of places where energy is lost as heat. Everywhere that a current flows through a wire, there is some heat lost due to resistance -- this heat increases with the square of the current. Heat is also lost in the switching components and the energy storage components. A well-designed switch-mode power supply may achieve 95% to 98% efficiency under some conditions. So suppose your inverter is a fantastic 98% efficient unit, then at 120W of load power it is only losing 2.56W for a total input power of 130.6W, and the input current is then 2.72A of input current.

The battery itself also leaks out some energy as heat -- this can be modeled as a resistor in series with an ideal voltage source. If the 48V battery is in a state of charge where its internal source resistance is 0.1 ohm, then a 7.5A load current will leak out 5.625W of electrical power as heat, and reduces the external terminal voltage to 47.25V -- you can't get the ideal 48V if you're drawing any power out of the battery. Note that a real battery is even more complicated, the idea of source resistance is just a simplified heuristic model we use to estimate how the system will work.

You mention charging a battery, presumably a different set of 48V batteries than the set that is being discharged by the inverter. The battery's internal resistance leaks out energy when the battery is discharging, but also when the battery is being charged. If your battery charger applies 48.123V to the external terminals of the 48V battery, and its internal resistance is 0.1 ohm, then there will be 1.23A of current flowing into the cells, however 152mW of heat will be lost to the internal resistance. More internal resistance means more heat lost when charging and discharging, more voltage needed to charge, and less voltage provided when discharging. As a battery ages and drains, its internal resistance increases, until it reaches a point where it can't deliver enough electrical energy to be useful.

Suppose you tried connecting a 48V battery charger to the inverter that is powered by another 48V battery. The battery that is providing energy to the inverter is being discharged, its voltage will be less than 48V because of the current flowing into the 120Vac inverter, and some heat will leak out of the discharging battery. Then this 120Vac inverter is powering a 48V battery charger -- this battery charger device is actually another power converter, just like the inverter, it has some efficiency less than 100% and so it loses some of the energy as heat. The output of the 48V battery charger has to be slightly more than 48V, because the battery has internal resistance that must be overcome to push energy into it.

What if you connected the 48.1V output of the battery charger to the input of the inverter, which is running at 47.9V? The output voltage is higher than the input voltage, so wouldn't it run forever?

No.

Energy gets lost as the battery discharges, more energy gets lost going through the inverter and the battery charger power converters. But even if the entire system was 100% efficient, consider what happens when the battery charger is providing 48.1V to a battery that is drawing 1A of current. Then the input battery must be providing at least 1.0041753A of current to the various power converters. If the power converters together were 98% efficient, the input battery would have to provide 1.025A while the output battery only receives 1A.

Conservation of energy applies to energy, but not voltage -- that's why it is possible to make power converters that boost lower voltage to higher voltage or step down a high voltage to a lower voltage. As long as volts x amps power is conserved everything is OK. (I'm skipping some potentially confusing details about how it works for AC.)

So if you tried to turn this system into a kind of oroborous or perpetual energy machine, by connecting the battery charger to the same batteries that are being discharged by the inverter and the battery charger, the batteries are going to end up discharged. I can't say how quickly or how violently this may happen. But I can guarantee that the battery will not end up charged.